# K6 distributed - starter/job are not created

Tags: k6

I am following this document to run K6 as distributed - https://k6.io/blog/running-distributed-tests-on-k8s/

Created config map to execute scenarios where I have to provide multiple files.
Created config map using

```
kubectl create configmap scenarios-test --from-file=archive.tar
```

I am trying to schedule a job using a config map like this. I tested the scenario execution locally and there is no issue.

```
apiVersion: k6.io/v1alpha1
kind: TestRun
metadata:
  name: k6-test
spec:
  parallelism: 4
  script:
    configMap:
      name: scenarios-test
      file: archive.tar
```

It creates only k6-test-initializer-rx5j8 pods. K6 is not creating starters and jobs.

Can you please provide any suggestions or documentation to debug this issue?
Thank you!